# factorisation of analytic functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

If I have an analytic function in plane $F(x,y)$ that is zero on a curve $y=f(x)$, is it true that
$F=(y-f(x))^n h$, where $h$ is nonzero on the curve? More general, can be somethink said about factorisation of analytic functions? How much is it determined by its zero set? Thx

Comment: You are using $f$ for two different things...

Comment: Thank you very much. Does somethink like that hold also over the reals? Peter

Comment: Yes it does....

Answer (score 3):

The answer is Weirstrass [preparation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_preparation_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

You need a combination of Weierstrass preparation and Puiseux series expansion to factor the analytic function, but it is indeed possible. Keep in mind that this is a local factorization near a point of your choice, that the factors may be complex valued and singular (=Holder continuous) at the point, but they are analytic outside the point. Better than writing here a lengthy explanation let me point you at a paper where I wrote all the details since I could not find them in the literature, although this stuff must be well known. See Section 2 of [this](http://www.informaworld.com/smpp/content~db=all~content=a713645852~frm=abslink) paper.

Comment: sorry, but the link to the paper doesn't work.

Comment: It is on Communications in PDEs, Volume 26, Issue 5-6, Pages 779-811